# Создание html элемента в js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Мне нужно создать div в div'е с помощью js.
Но вместо этого получается лишь '[object HTMLDivElement]' внутри div'а

Код, который я имею:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.block2');

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('item');
div.innerHTML = document.createElement('div');

container.append(div);
```

```html
<div class="block2"></div>
```

Comment: Вот ты делаешь `container.append`. Почему ты думаешь, что для  `div` нужно делать что-то другое?

Comment: не понял вопроса. я не говорил что для div нужно делать что-то другое. мне лишь нужно создать div в dive с помощью js внутри родительского контейнера

Comment: Ну если не нужно делать что-то другое, то зачем ты делаешь это самое другое?

Comment: Это вообще твой код? Ты знаешь что делает код `container.append(div)` ?

Comment: ну по идее добавляет div с классом item внутрь conteiner'a.

Comment: Так почему ты считаешь, что добавить `div` внутрь другого `div` делается как-то по-другому? А судя по твоему коду ты именно так считаешь

Comment: но этого мало. мне нужно чтобы добавлялся не только один div внутрь container'a, а два, причем второй вложенный в первый.

Comment: я считаю что div добавляется внутрь другого div`a по другому потому что у меня это не работает

Comment: Как ты это проверял? И главное, как ты это писал?

Comment: я же прикрепил скриншот. вместо '[object HTMLDivElement]' должен быть еще один div

Comment: Нет, этот скриншот ты сделал на основе кода, который сейчас у тебя в вопросе..... А ты говоришь, что у тебя метод добавления, аналогичный методу добавления в контенйр не работает и поэтому ты считаешь что добавлять надо как-то по-другому.....

Comment: так получилось, что мы не поняли друг друга. давайте сначала. как добавить div внутри div`a?

Comment: А как ты добавляешь один из div'ов внутрь контейнера?

Comment: давай попробую по другому вопрос задать. Что по твоему должно произойти при `div.innerHTML = document.createElement('div')`?

Comment: Почему при добавлении одного `div` ты используешь`.append`, при добавлении второго пытаешься использовать что то другое, например `innerHTML`?

Comment: Именно об этом тебя и спрашивает @АлексейШиманский

Comment: я теперь понял, попробую переписать код. но изначально я думал innerHTML добавит в div новый элемент div. а append добавит внутрь контейнера уже готовые div в divе

Comment: да, у меня получилось это сделать. спасибо большое!

Comment: ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) возвращает [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), а это - объект

У вас есть много путей это сделать. Но если оставить логику вашего кода, то вам нужно достать [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) у созданного элемента:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.block2');

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('item');
div.innerHTML = document.createElement('div').outerHTML;

container.append(div);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2"></div>
```

Но будет лучше использовать метод [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append):

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.block2');

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('item');
div.append(document.createElement('div'));

container.append(div);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2"></div>
```